# Access values from LINQ GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query looking like this:

```
            var myGrouping = (
                from p in context.Products
                join pt in context.ProductTypes on p.productId equals pt.productId
                select new
                {
                    ProductName = p.productName,
                    Type = pt.productType
                }).GroupBy(x => x.ProductName ).ToList();
```

This gives me what I'm looking for, a group for each ProductName with the Types displayed with them. Now, what I'm looking to do is check each group and see if the ProductType ever differs INSIDE these groupings, which is an error I sometimes get in the database.

I've tried a few things to access this data, and it seems like I can use `item.Distinct().Skip(1).Any()` to check through these groupings and see if they differ. Problem is only that I don't know how to access the ProductName and Type, to loop over it. I've tried things like

`foreach (IGrouping<string, string?> ProductGroup in myGrouping)`

and things along those lines but it never seems accessable. My question is, how do I access elements in IGroupings like this?

Comment: what is your expected output after grouping?

Comment: My expected output is the one I'm getting, I get groups of <ProductName, Type>. So one group can be, for example,
<Phone, iPhone>

<Phone, iPhone>

<Phone, Nexus>

Comment: please share Products and ProductTypes  classes @Eric

Comment: You can't access means what?. like, No error but you can't access or getting error while accessing? if getting error means post here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When using `GroupBy` you can access:

- the Key by which was sorted with `list.Key`
- the List for each group with `list.ToList()`

So:

```
foreach(var group in input.GroupBy(it => it.Sort)) 
{
    var sort = group.Key;
    var list = group.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works well!

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
 var myGrouping = (
            from p in context.Products
            join pt in context.ProductTypes on p.productId equals pt.productId
            select new
            {
                ProductName = p.productName,
                Type = pt.productType
            }).GroupBy(x => new{x.ProductName,x.Type } ).Select(x=>new {ProductName =x.Key.ProductName ,Type=x.Key.Type}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not really following though - how do I access these elements?